# openFDA endpoints not updated in over 2 months. Has this project been abandoned?

Tags: openfda

We are specifically interested in the "Devices › Adverse Events" data which until recently seemed to get updated monthly, usually within 2 weeks of the end of the month.  We realize that this is a beta project, but would like to know when we can expect updated data to be available?

Answer (score 2):

The endpoints were updated on 08/12, and, no, the project is very much active.

Comment: can you clarify with more information please? how you know that, where you found that, etc.?

Comment: I'm one of the many folks working on Open FDA (https://open.fda.gov/about/)

Comment: Thanks Denis, we appreciate your efforts.  Will the API status page at https://open.fda.gov/api/status/ be updated going forward?

Comment: Yes, we've fixed the bug that is responsible for the incorrect display of Last Updated (2015-01-01). It will be included in our next update. Sorry about the inconvenience.