# openFDA - update notice:: further clarification

Tags: openfda

A little more clarification, please.  I see the Q/A here [openFDA endpoints not updated in over 2 months. Has this project been abandoned?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9362/openfda-endpoints-not-updated-in-over-2-months-has-this-project-been-abandoned)
regarding the bug and update status.

Did the bug and will future fixes also relate to the values of the  tags in the XML provided via download.open.fda.gov?

I have been using that xml to "automatically" check whether stuff has changed, and just over the weekend, I noticed that dates that appeared in the LastModified json field within some of the files themselves were newer than the xml tag contents.

Of course the premise of my questions could reveal other confusion.  Any redirection most welcome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend checking `export_date` attribute in [this JSON](https://api.fda.gov/download.json) instead. The [XML](http://download.open.fda.gov/) will only show first 1000 of items in the S3 bucket and thus is not reliable.